# How to check method type of RequestMethod using Angular 2 MockBackend

Tags: angular, mocking, conditional-statements, backend, equality-operator

I use Angular 2 MockBackend to mock the result and set the response depends on method type (Post|Get|...). For example:

```
if (connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate') && connection.request.method === RequestMethod.Post) {
```

But I have errors while compiling. For example:

```
[default] ...
Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'RequestMethod.Post' and 'RequestMethod.Get'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeof` and `indexOf` instead:

```
connection.request.url.endsWith('/api/authenticate') && [typeof connection.request.method].indexOf(typeof RequestMethod.Post) !== -1
```

**References**

- [Fun with JavaScript Native Array Functions - Modern Web](https://modernweb.com/fun-with-javascript-native-array-functions/)
- [Sequences using JavaScript Array · ariya.io](https://ariya.io/2013/07/sequences-using-javascript-array)